# jquery zoom 4 circles one by one

Tags: jquery, css, animation, element

I am trying to achieve an effect of zooming in/out (or pulsing) 4 circles one by one. For example pulse A and when A is finished pulse B..and so on..

So far I have an effect which pulse all of them every 4 seconds which is good. Now just to separate them. Can anyone help me with this?

```
function pulseCircles() {
    if($(".header-banner .emo-faces").not(":hover")) {
        var $object = $(".header-banner .emo-faces");
        var delay = 4000;
        var delay2 = 2000;
            setTimeout(function() {
                $($object).addClass("pulse2");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $($object).removeClass("pulse2");
                    pulseCircles();
                }, delay2);
            }, delay);
    }
};
pulseCircles();
```

EDIT:

```
<div class="emo-faces">
    <a href="<?php echo get_tag_link(169); ?>" class="emj smile yellow icon-emo-happy"></a>
    <a href="<?php echo get_tag_link(167); ?>" class="emj suprise green icon-emo-suprised"></a>
    <a href="<?php echo get_tag_link(168); ?>" class="emj sad brown icon-emo-sad"></a>
    <a href="<?php echo get_tag_link(170); ?>" class="emj angry red icon-emo-angry"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have some HTML too? A runnable snippet would be great.

Comment: Please add relevant html and css as well. [mcve]

Comment: I added the html snippet.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to do that by this:

```
function LoopZooming() {
    $(".emo-faces li").each(function(i) {
        var $li = $(this);
        var $prev = $(this).prev();

        $timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $prev.removeClass("pulse2");
            $li.addClass("pulse2");
            setTimeout(function() {
                if (i === 3) {
                    $li.removeClass("pulse2");
                }
            },2000);
        }, i*2000);
        $timer;
    });
};

var $interval = setInterval(LoopZooming, 10000);
$interval;

$(".emo-faces li").hover(
    function() {
        clearInterval($interval);
        StopLoopZooming();
    },
    function() {
        var $interval = setInterval(LoopZooming, 10000);
        $interval;
    }
);
```